# How to delimit point distances in ArcGIS for Desktop per Thiessen polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, distance, batch, voronoi-thiessen

I have 2 shapefiles. The first set contains x,y coordinates for 1100 hospital locations. The second pair contains x,y coordinates of about 7000 villages that are served by the hospitals. This means each hospital serves villages defined by Thiessen polygons. I need to calculate distance from each hospital to the corresponding villages in a specific Thiessen polygon. I can calculate this from the point distance in ArcGIS, but how will I get the distances per Thiessen?

Comment: From your tags I'm guessing you want an arcpy solution? Do you have code started you could post? Do you have a way to identify the two sets (e.g. all of the shapefiles are in a folder or gbd) and which goes with which (e.g. an ID or naming convention)?

Comment: how about merging the data: all hospitals, all villages, do one Generate Near Table and then extract the results... you can add the original file names to the hospitals and villages to make it easier to extract the matching pair. Are the hospitals and villages named in a similar fashion? i.e. X_village matches X_hospital? How is the data stored? Are the hospitals and villages in the same folder.. how can we equate one hospital to one village?

Comment: Do you really have 2200 shapefiles or do you have 1100 features in each of two shapefiles?  Please **edit** your question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Initially I had just two shapefiles but using an extension I broke them down hoping to get a python Solution. An arcpy solution would do.

Comment: Bad idea. Without this simple spatial join would do the job

Comment: I tried getting the distance from all hospitals to all villages but extracting the distances that I need, I couldn't find a way. Thiessen polygons were used to define what villages belong to a specific hopsital

Comment: @Chris W, am trying to implement your solution, the aim of the thiessen polygons were to know if a person is sick (a resident of the village) which is the most near hospital. With this in mind i calculate for each thissen polygon how far a person has to travel or walk from each each village to the hospital, from these distances i will tell the minimum , maximum and average  distance a person has to walk to get to the most nearest(thiessen polygon identified this) hospital and advice accordingly. in some thiessen  the hospital maybe too far.Its part of a study, other factors are catered for

Comment: FYI, no spaces in name for @ notifications to work. It sounds like you should drop the Thiessen / pairing villages and hospitals from the analysis altogether (it confused me when I saw this added to the question). Unless your Thiessen is creating regions with multiple hospitals and villages (and from what points in that case) and you want statistics by region. Thiessen *isn't* telling you the nearest hospital from a village; the only distance component is lines are equidistant between paired points. A simple spatial join one-to-one nearest or Near tool would get you what it appears you want.

Comment: @ChrisW I used the method you suggested initially and it worked well, its only that the i had to mange huge txt data, but R became useful, I have attained the objective. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly easy problem to solve if you just brute force it and doesn't require any automation. The question is basically a duplicate of [Calculating all distances from single points to multiple polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126639/)

The key piece of information you need is an attribute in villages that defines which hospital they belong to. Since you've already generated Thiessen polygons for the hospitals* all you need to do is intersect those polygons with the village points and you should have a hospital ID as an attribute of the points.

Then you can run the Generate Near Table tool with hospitals and villages as the inputs. The resulting table will have the distance from every hospital to every village. Since you only want specific hospitals to specific villages, you'll then do a select by attribute where the hospital feature ID attribute matches the hospital ID attribute in the village file and export those records to a new table.

---

*This method has issues. You have 1100 hospitals and only 7000 villages. Thiessen creates non-overlapping polygons for each point, so that means you have 4000 hospitals that serve no village, and this doesn't really make sense. It's unclear from your question why the association between hospital and village might be based on anything other than distance (unless population is a factor, which you haven't mentioned and Thiessen wouldn't account for). If you want to associate a hospital with a village, you could use a Spatial Join with a 'within a distance of' method to get an identifying/matching attribute.

It's also unclear exactly what your goal is. If you want to find the a) nearest, or b) nearest x hospitals to any given village, simply running on the two original files a) Spatial Join as FelixIP suggests or the Near tool, or b) the Generate Near Table tool which allows you to specify return x matches.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your use of Thiessen polygons. If you ran it on villages and are looking for the distance from each village to the hospitals within, the answer stays largely the same but with a little reversal and I can edit appropriately. But I still think Thiessen might not be the best way to assign hospitals to villages.