# Calculating distance from centroid points to multiple polygon edges with SpatialLite

Tags: qgis, spatialite, distance-matrix

My question builds on a question previously asked ([Calculating all distances from single points to multiple polygons](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126639/calculating-all-distances-from-single-points-to-multiple-polygons)). User [@alexandre-neto](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/6191/alexandre-neto) provided an answer that I've worked on, but it isn't giving me the result I need. I'm new to SpatialLite and using QGIS 3.6 on a Windows OS.

I've created a SpatialLite database that has a point and a polygon layer. The point layer is the centroid of a sampling grid and the polygon layer comes from a government database called the 'Vegetation Resource Inventory (VRI)', which includes lots of data on stand age, species composition, wetlands, etc...

I want to create a new layer or a table of distances from the centroid of my sampling grid (Named: `"Grid Pothole Center"`) to the nearest edge of the VRI polygon layer (Named: `"Pothole VRI")`. It looks like SpatialLite offers a way to do this. I used the following code from instructions on the link provided above:

```
SELECT
  f.id,
  g.id,
  st_distance(f.geom, st_centroid(g.geom)) AS distance

FROM
 'Grid Pothole Center' AS f,
 'Pothole VRI' AS g
```

Note: `'Grid Pothole Center'` and `'Pothole VRI'` have a common field called `'id'`. This runs from the SpatiaLite DB manager plugin (select the database and ran the SQL statement above) without any error messages and a result is given. However, I get an empty table x with the following headings: `id, id:1, distance` - but no data in the table. What have I done wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Works for me with test data that I created according to your description. I made a successful test both with spatialite_gui program and with QGIS 3.4.4 (see the image). Is the name of your geometry column certainly "geom"?

[image]

Notice that your SQL is actually wrong because by the SQL standard `SELECT … FROM 'Grid Pothole Center'` means "select from string `Grid Pothole Center`" The table name should be enclosed between double quotation marks, but SQLite is lenient and really accepts also single quotes in this case. Still, take a habit to use double quotes in the future.

Comment: Thank you for explanations, especially using `"double quotes"`

Comment: I rebooted and re-ran with success. I checked and the geometry column was "geom". I'll add a more comprehensive response when I get this complete, because there are a few more steps I've followed to get the data I'm after. I think this is a useful post, because I have not seen a full description of this posted here.